# Finding a constant that satisfies inequality

Tags: inequality

Let every $a_{k}$ >0 then I have to find a constant $c_{2}$ such that

$a_{k} +\frac{a_{k-1}}{n} + \frac{a_{k-2}}{n^2} +...+\frac{a_{0}}{n^k} \le c_{2} $ which is true  for some $n_{0} $ where  $n \ge n_{0}$,In my textbook it is said that any number $c_{2}>a_{k}$ is suitable.Well what if $a_{k}=1 , \frac{a_{k-1}}{n} + \frac{a_{k-2}}{n^2} +...+\frac{a_{k}}{n^k} =\frac{1}{2} , c_{2}=1.3$ I think that is counterexample?

Comment: Can you elaborate why,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The question is to find a $c_2$ such that there exists an $n_0$ such that for every $n \ge n_0$ the equation $a_{k} +\frac{a_{k-1}}{n} + \frac{a_{k-2}}{n^2} +...+\frac{a_{0}}{n^k} \le c_{2}$ holds.

Note that when the equation holds for a certain $n$, then it also holds for greater $n$, because the left side of the equation gets smaller when $n$ gets higher. So we can simplify the question to:

Find a $c_2$ such that there exists an $n_0$ such that the equation $a_{k} +\frac{a_{k-1}}{n_0} + \frac{a_{k-2}}{{n_0}^2} +...+\frac{a_{0}}{{n_0}^k} \le c_{2}$ holds.

Your example is not a counterexample, because if you take $n$ high enough, then $\frac{a_{k-1}}{n} + \frac{a_{k-2}}{n^2} +...+\frac{a_{k}}{n^k}$ becomes as small as you want. Always bigger than 0 though.

Note that $1 + \frac12 = 1.5 \le 1.8$, so that wouldn't be a counterexample anyway. But I interpreted your question as if you had chosen some number between 1 and 1.5 for $c_2$.

Comment: Ops,yes $c_{2}$ should be 1.3 for example then this is counterexample?

Comment: No, because $\frac{a_{k-1}}{n} + \frac{a_{k-2}}{n^2} +...+\frac{a_{k}}{n^k} < 0.3$ for $n$ big enough.